# Serial downvoting

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, serial-voting

My answers are continuously being down-voted by group of people from last two days. In my point of view, my answers are fairly legitimate.

During my investigation, I noticed there was a message on reputation tab that  it says "voting corrected".I just wanted to know that Is there any way I can email/informed  directly to the moderator?

[image]

Comment: if the voting was corrected, why do you want to email the moderator?

Comment: @eis:Its only +4 but I have lost 150 points

Comment: Where have you lost 150 points? I can't see it in your reputation overview.

Comment: @Santosh you really should explain that in your question

Comment: All of the downvoted posts in your reputation history are link only answers. You've gotten comments from multiple different users on them, pointing that out to you. This looks like a link-only-answer cleanup effort.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:Yesterday my point was 8145 and today it is 8095

Comment: @ff524 indeed. I am tempted to down-vote... But I won't.

Comment: Was an answer of yours deleted? In the reputation overview click to show deleted posts too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:Yes , You are right.I deleted all the answers that are downvoted yesterday

Comment: So... You expected to keep the reputation for those posts? A single down vote doesn't hurt. If you feel the answer is bad: delete it. If not: keep it.

Comment: Or better yet... fix it.

Comment: So, you will delete an answer of yours with 10000 upvotes just because you got a single downvote? Wow.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:I investigated and found that those answer are downvoted which have link

Comment: Indeed. And nothing more than a link. A valid reason to downvote and even to delete.

Comment: You can open any question you want, right? And every post that appears in a review queue is handled by any user, not just users in a specific tag.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:Got it thanks for your help :)

Comment: A user doesn't have to know about the technical content of an answer to see that it's a link-only answer. I believe many other users have already posted comments on your downvoted answers, explaining why answers should be more than just a link.

Comment: @ff524: Agree with you.But these answers are very old at that time stackoverflow allows the link as answer.

Comment: So, people are alerting you to answers that need fixing. Go ahead and fix them, and problem solved.

Comment: @ff524:Sure today I will fixed all the answers :)

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that `8145 - 8095` is `50`, not `150`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, there is nothing to report. The secret script that runs every day noticed some serial voting and reversed the votes. From the three votes visible there, two were reversed.

If you notice suspicious activity and you want notify a moderator, first wait 24 hours for the script to run and then flag one of your own posts with a custom message explaining what you think happened.

A moderator will review your flag, which may take a few days.